# Kevo Second Generation Android — Connection Issue

Tags: smart-home, smart-lock

I'm pairing a Kevo second generation to an Android Samsung s5 (similarly on iPhone XR). It seems to successfully pair (I'm required to reset at the end), however when I'm expecting a completion I receive the following error.

"connection error - please ensure your device has proper internet connection." - android
"new lock error - there was an issue setting up this lock. Please try again"
ios

Is this referring to the Kevo connection (Bluetooth) or the Samsung (or Iphone) smartphone connection? As you can see Samsung is shown as connected to the internet.

How can I work past this?

[image: Android Error]

[image: iOS Error]

Comment: Are setting up an internet connection for your lock in that steps? Maybe the device cannot connect past the router to some internet server.

Comment: I called support and they are sending out a new device. Perhaps the manufacturer can add more authoritative information?